# Handling exception in sql user defined type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user defined type which have almost all fields as decimal and one is of big int.

But i dont know why I am getting this exception:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
>   The data for table-valued parameter "@DataTable" doesn't 
>   conform to the table type of the parameter.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I am not passing any nvarchar value to the type.
Here is defination of type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DataTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Total1] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
    [Total2] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
    [Total3] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total4] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total5] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total6] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total7] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total8] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total9] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total10] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total11] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total12] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total13] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total14] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total15] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
        [Total16] [int] NULL,
)
```

and this is the set that is being sent from c#

```
[0]= 12869
[1]= 54899440.29
[2] = 0
[3] = 0
[4] = 0
[5] = 54899440.29
[6] = 0
[7] = 82000000000.00
[8] = 54899440.29
[9] = 54899440.29
[10] = 0
[11] = 0
[12]= -81945100559.71 
[13] = 0.0
[14] = 0
[15] = 2013
```

Comment: In column 7 and 12 you are trying to insert number greater than your field.

Comment: Then how can i handle that? and how is it greater.I have already taken (20,10) as precision.

Comment: `5489944.0.29` have 2 decimal points... (second value)

Comment: that was by mistake. type error

Comment: Well, you can (or even you have to) expand your columns to e.g. `decimal(25,10)`. [There](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187746(v=sql.110).aspx) is documentation about decimals.

Comment: And the comma after the first value? Seeing the code might help debugging...

Comment: @ZoharPeled that was also by mistake. sorry for sillymistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column 7 and 12 you are trying to insert numbers greater than you defined in your fields. If field is type of `decimal(20,10)` means that you can store in it numbers which have at most ten digits on left side of the decimal point and at most ten digits on right of the decimal point. If you provide bigger number then `9999999999` (ten 9) then SQL will throw exception (as in question).

There are at least two options. You can create new `TYPE` with "bigger" fields (e.g. `decimal(25,10)`) or drop this one and then recreate it. (you can't alter fields in `TYPE` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)).

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187746(v=sql.110).aspx) about `decimal` and `numeric` data types.